# How to pull the license stored in different table against a Userid in another activity table(at a specific time)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table which store each user's activity in a table named as **"UserActivity"**. In **"UserActivity.Params"** column (Json data), against each activity, **"userID"** and some other information of user is stored. In another table **"License"** the license_name to which a user subscribed is stored. So, i need to get the exact License_name for a **userID** at that specific time **(Not the current License on which user is using)**. The problem is that the user can subscribe to another License as well, and only License creation date and License expiration date is stored.

**Postgresql Code#**

```
select A.Month,Count(distinct A.User) as Users,B.Plan
        (
            select date_trunc('month', CAST(Te.created_at AS timestamp)) as "Month", UA.params ->> 'UserID' as User 
            FROM public.UserActivity UA
            WHERE Te.event_type = 'StartSession'
            and Te.created_at between('20181201') and ('20181231')
        )AS A 
left Join
        (
            select Lcs.user as User,Lcs.License_id as Plan
            from public.license Lcs 
            group by 1,2
        ) as B
on A.User=B.User
group by 1,3
```

**Data Stored in UserActivity Table**

```
 created_at|event_Type|Params
 ----------|---------------|--------------------------------
 2018-12-01|StartedSession |{"UserID": "Huges1", "userName": "Huges"} 
 ----------|---------------|---------------------------------
 2018-12-02|StartedSession |{"UserID": "Huges1", "userName": "Huges"}
 ----------|---------------|--------------------------------
 2018-12-30|StartedSession |{"UserID": "Huges1", "userName": "Huges"}
 ----------|---------------|--------------------------------
 2018-12-18|StartedSession |{"UserID": "Martin1", "userName": "Martin"}
```

**Data Stored in License Table**

```
 created_at|user_id|License_name|License_id|expires_at
 ----------|-------|------------|----------|----------
 2018-11-01|Huges1 |Enterprise  |Entrpr    |2019-01-27
 ----------|-------|------------|----------|----------
 2018-12-14|Martin1|Enterprise  |Entrpr    |2019-01-14
 ----------|-------|------------|----------|----------
 2019-01-29|Huges1 |Studio      |Std       |2019-04-31
```

Output =

```
Month  |Users|Plan
1. Dec |2    |Entrpr
2. Dec |1    |Std
```

Expected Output = (It should count Huges in one plan only and that is Entrpr Not in **"std"**, because he was active in **"Entrpr"** in december activities.)

```
Month  |Users|Plan
1. Dec |2    |Entrpr
```

Comment: Please show us the other table as well. Please add the expected output

Comment: Added the expected output as well as the data in the other table

Comment: So you want to get the licenses that where active completely within a certain date range? martin is not in because his license began after dec-1, right?

Comment: Martin is included in the output because his active plan is of december, thats why entrpr license count is 2. But the problem is that i only want Huges in entrpr. not in studio. Because, his active plan was entrpr only in dec. That's one case only, there are alot of users in actual data like that.

Comment: It would be easier if your `license` table stored the start **and** the end of the period for which the license is valid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is storing created_date and expiration_date. So created_date is the start_date and expiration_date is the end date. So, how can it be done? can you please guide me about it ?